# How to merge two adjacency matrices into one in R

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have two adjacency matrices made from edgelists, `mat1` and `mat2`

```
> mat1
     A B C D 
[A,] 0 0 0 0 
[B,] 0 0 1 0 
[C,] 1 0 0 0 
[D,] 0 1 0 0 

> mat2
     A B C D 
[A,] 0 0 1 1 
[B,] 1 0 0 0 
[C,] 0 1 0 0 
[D,] 1 0 0 0
```

How do I merge the values in the two matrices to one matrix to look like this?

```
> mat_new
     A B C D 
[A,] 0 0 1 1 
[B,] 1 0 1 0 
[C,] 1 1 0 0 
[D,] 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: Does `mat1 + mat2` works?

Comment: Yes, that simple! It does turn 1s to 2s where edge exists in both matrices but that can be dealt with. Thank you!

Comment: `(mat1 + mat2) %% 1`

Comment: `+(mat1 + mat2 > 0)`

Comment: Yeah, I'm wrong. Use @MerijnvanTilborg 's suggestion.